# my values are sometimes read and sometimes ignored in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

So here's the sum of it:

```
<script>
//hard coded these to simplify my code
var startDate  = '01-01-2013';
var endDate    = '01-31-2013';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ReportStartDays').val(startDate);
  $('#ReportEndDays').val(endDate);
}

jQuery('#Report').jqGrid({
//Sometimes these grab the right values, and sometimes it doesn't
//ReportStartDays.val();
//ReportEndDays.val()
});
</script>
```

Anyone know why my report inputs don't work correctly? sometimes it grabs them, and sometimes it doesn't. If I put `startDate` and `endDate` within the ready function then for some reason they don't get initialize fast enough for the new values to be read from jQuery function. Any ideas?

Comment: Without posting all of your code, it's impossible to debug anything. Try recreating the issue inside of a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to look at.

Comment: Provide your HTML mark up.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the code in `$(window).load(function` .. instead.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var startDate  = '01-01-2013';
  var endDate    = '01-31-2013';


  $('#ReportStartDays').val(startDate);
  $('#ReportEndDays').val(endDate);

  startDate = $('#ReportStartDays').val();
  endDate = $('#ReportStartDays').val();    

  $('#Report').jqGrid({
     'some_param' : startDate,
     'some_param' : endDate
  });
});
```

I did create a sample fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bambattajb/dk7PF/). Since I'm not executing the `jqGrid` method I just added the values in HTML to try and demonstrate.

I assume also that when you reference your method `jqGrid` that you are applying these values to parametres, in which case you can try using global vars.

Anyway - this idea should be in the ballpark